# Streaming movies from my server

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I'm playing around to make an app that lets people stream cartoons that I make. It's a very simple app, one ImageView is just loading in a html-homepage in a UIWebView. Witch contain  links to .mov files. So if you tap them a movie will start playing. This is because I just want to update the html-file with new cartoons every week.

Is this an "ok" way to do things code:ing-wise? Or am i obligated to us some Objective-c streaming functions?
Is there a specific file-type that i have to use in the movie-files on the server?

Comment: If you want to make sure that users get the best possible experience, no matter how flaky their network is, then you should aim for HTTP-streaming (m3u8). If you dont care about that, using mp4-video files or even mov-files might do. Make sure you adhere to the correct codec choice and resultion parameters. There are MANY pitfalls in encoding video correctly for mobile usage.

Answer (score 0):

Is the HTML static in your app, or does it point to a server? If it's the former, you *may* be able to get the app approved doing it the way you suggested, depending on the reviewer. If it's the latter, you're unlikely to get it approved by apple.

They tend to frown upon web sites bundled into apps, and will tell you to simply make your website usable with the phone. See [section 2.12](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html).

My suggestion is to spend a bit more time and offer iOS users a better - and more immersive - experience than is available via the web. As I'm sure you've found, there are many built-in ways to stream movies and to present them in a manner that surpasses a web-page-like experience.

Comment: Well.. It's just a UIwebview that loads a HTML file from a my webserver.. Si i guess thats not good? Hiw should i do this? I want to be abel to have the movies on a server and web i ad a new one the users shukdrnt have to update the APP itself to se the new episode.

Comment: I don't know anything about your skill level, resources, or much about your site... so it's difficult to make any concrete recommendations. I can give you an example of how you may do it simply.

You can create a JSON service on your site, easily import that into your app when it starts up (see AFNetworking), and use the data to populate a table. That table can then open videos when a cell is tapped. But even that may not be approved due to its simplicity.